# PHP, SQL, Apostrophe, text input

Tags: php, sql, text, textinput, apostrophe

for some reason when I replace an apostrophe with a double apostrophe it will work for a textview but not a regular text input. (I'm using phpFusion).

This is my HTML code

```
<tr class='" . $class_alt . "'>

                                    <td class='first'><input type='text' class='w_focus validate[required] text-input' size='20' name='track' id='race' value='" . $data['track'] . "' /></td>
                                    <td><input type='text' class='w_focus validate[required] text-input' size='1' name='race' id='race' value='" . $data['race'] . "' /></td>
                                    <td><input type='text' class='w_focus validate[required] text-input' size='1' name='turnip_number' id='turnip_number' value='" . $data['turnip_number'] . "' /></td>
                                    <td><input type='text' class='w_focus validate[required] text-input' size='20' name='turnip_horse' id='turnip_horse' value='" . $data['turnip_horse'] . "' /></td>
                                    <td><input type='text' class='w_focus validate[required] text-input' size='3' name='turnip_odds' id='turnip_odds' value='" . $data['turnip_odds'] . "' /></td>
                                    <td><input type='text' class='w_focus validate[required] text-input' size='10' name='turnip_bettype' id='turnip_bettype' value='" . $data['turnip_bettype'] . "' /></td>
                                    <td><input type='text' class='w_focus validate[required] text-input' size='1' name='turnip_special' id='turnip_special' value='" . $data['turnip_special'] . "' /></td>
                                    <td>
                        <div class='textarea'>
                            <textarea cols='20' rows='12' name='turnip_reason' id='turnip_reason' class='w_focus validate[required]'>" . $data['turnip_reason'] . "</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                                    <td class='last'>
                        <div class='send'><span class='button_lnk blue def_link'>
                            <input type='submit' value='Enter Tip' class='enter_tips' name='enter_tips'/>
                        </span></div>
                    </td>

                </tr>
```

And my SQL query:

```
$find = "'";
$replace = "''";

$result = dbquery("UPDATE fusion6618n_tips SET turnip_horse='" . str_replace($find, $replace, $_POST['turnip_horse']) . "', turnip_number='" . $_POST['turnip_number'] . "', turnip_odds='" . $_POST['turnip_odds'] . "', turnip_bettype='" . str_replace($find, $replace, $_POST['turnip_bettype']) . "', turnip_special='" . $_POST['turnip_special'] . "', turnip_reason='" . str_replace($find, $replace, $_POST['turnip_reason']) . "' WHERE track='" . $_POST['track'] . "' AND race='" . $_POST['race'] . "'");
```

It works fine for the textview (turnip_reason).

But if I do it for a text input, (turnip_horse), and say "Sir 'n' Sausage" is entered, all that get's updated in the database is "Sir " instead of Sir ''n'' Sausage.

And I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: please read [`How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). It will help address your issue.

Comment: I've tried $safe_variable = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['chief_horse']);

Same problem, is that what you were referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You have replace escaping ' sign, not doubling them. So your part code should be:

`$find = "'";
$replace = "\'";`

because your query (simplified) in the middle is escaping:

`UPDATE fusion6618n_tips SET turnip_horse='Sir ''n'' Sausage' WHERE track=''`

`UPDATE fusion6618n_tips SET turnip_horse='Sir '`